# How to make a command that only effects players in a certain gamemode

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

As of right now I have

```
/gamemode adventure @a [r=40, name=!"contract to kil"]
```

Which update other players gamemode but it continue to do so until lagging, I want it to exclude players already in adventure to prevent lag.

I've tried adding:

`[gamemode=!adventure]`

but it doesn't work

Comment: I am voting to close this as being off topic and more appropriate for [Arqade SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I was looking for another solution to a different problem and stumbled upon the answer
M=2 is adventure
So I plugged in m=!2 Which stopped the constant updating and lagging, stress relieved...